# ChartJS - Display one set of data at a time

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to do a couple of things with ChartJS, but I can't find the information I need in the docs and they don't seem to have a forum or anywhere useful to ask questions.

The main thing I'm trying to accomplish is to have only one set of data displayed at a time. I was able to hide the one set on load, but when you click on it, I can't figure out how to hide the first. Eventually I might have 3 sets and would need to be sure the other two are hidden. I've read how to grab the click event, but I'm not sure what to return.

I'd also like to be able to customize the title & label text/layout, but I'm not sure if this is doable.

Here's what I have so far for code:

```
var ctx = $("#myChart");
var data = {
  labels: ["LABEL1", "LABEL2", "LABEL3", "LABEL4", "LABEL5"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "DATA1",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(62,135,74,.5)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#34b44a",
      data: [3, 3, 4, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      label: "DATA2",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      data: [2, 2, 4, 4, 3],
      hidden: true
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  title: {
    display: true,
    fontColor: '#999',
    fontStyle: 'regular',
    fullWidth: false,
    text: 'CHART TITLE'
  },
  legend: {
    fullWidth: false,
    labels: {
      fontColor: '#fff',
      boxWidth: 0
    }
  },
  elements: {
    line: {
    }
  },
  scale: {
    angleLines: {
      color: '#666'
    },
    gridLines: {
      color: '#666'
    },
    pointLabels: {
      fontColor: '#fff'
    },
    ticks: {
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
      stepSize: 1,
      display: false
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  }
};

var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

You can see it here with the design on the right: http://codepen.io/haxen2000/pen/jBVMqK

Comment: Did you already find a solution?  I was checking out your codepend and it looks like you have implemented buttons to show the different datasets.

Comment: Yes, apologies. I meant to make is a separate pen. Doing that now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pen to my solution: http://codepen.io/haxen2000/pen/evgwmB

I just took out what I needed and made them HTML elements so I could style as needed. Would be nice to see a solution from within the ChartJS code, but this will work.

```
<div class='header'>
  <span class='title'>CHART TITLE</span>
  <button id='data1'>DATA1</button>
  <button id='data2'>DATA2</button>
</div>
```